# Ellipsis multiline Text

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a GridView and each item should have a title, a description and a button.

I made my GridItem like this

```
Card(
    color: Colors.white,
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(data[position]),
          Expanded(
            child: Text(desctiption, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
          ),
          MaterialButton(
            child: Text("open"),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ));
```

My description text is using ellipsis, but it is only showing one line of the text. I want it to use all the space it has verticaly and then use ellipsis at the end of the last line.
now it looks like this

[image]

Comment: There is a property named `maxLines` in `Text` Widget, you can use that.

Comment: I tried that it has no effect for me. 
Also would be nicer if the maxLines would be detected automatically by the space the Widget has to display the text.

Comment: When I use `maxLines` it the `ellipsis` is gone and the text is still in one line.

Comment: maybe you should consider using this https://github.com/letsar/flutter_staggered_grid_view

Answer (score 0):

What I am getting from your post and others comments you want to wrap the texts. To do that remove overflow property from Text widget. For maximum amount of line you can add maxLines property.

Kinda like this:

Text('your long texts......', maxLines: 3, styles: TextStyle(.....));

Answer (score -1):

Specify both the `maxLines` and `overflow` properties of the Text widget, like this:

```dart
Text("Very long text here", maxLines: 3, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis)
```